# Write a program to count number of lines from a text files that ends at ‘.’

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
 #include<fstream.h>
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt");
    char ch[50];
    int count=0,i;
    for(i=0;infile.eof()==0;i++)
    {
        infile.getline(ch,50);
        if(ch[i]=='\n')
            if(ch[i-1]=='.')
                count++;
    }
    cout<<"Total number of lines are:"<<count;
}
```

I tried this code but it doesnt seem to work.I used the logic to take all the file contents in ch and then subsequently check for newline character and '.'
      How do I make it work.
Please help?

**EDIT** new code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt");
    char ch[50];
    int count=0,i;
    while(!infile.eof())
    {

        infile.getline(ch,50);
        for(i=1;ch[i]!='\n';i++);
        if(ch[i-1]=='.')
                count++;    

    }
    cout<<"Total number of lines are:"<<count;
}
```

Comment: add some debugging to your loop to look at what you read in, your index variable etc...

Comment: @Nim i tried that, I guess the loop is not running properly

Comment: don't guess, try to understand what is happening with that variable, and what `getline()` is doing...

Comment: ...and how often it is doing it...

Comment: You're checking wrong. variable `i` in this case counts the number of lines you've read, yet you use it to access the index inside an array of chars.

Comment: Please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: As for your problem, learn about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: also, `eof()` returns a boolean, don't compare it to a number, specially where a boolean is expected!

Comment: With new code, you don't care about some of comments : **don't use** `eof` in condition of `while` and don't compare  boolean variable with an integer (just write `!infile.eof()` or `infile.eof() == false`)

Comment: Read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: @user3500780 some advice still missing, see JoachimPileborg and molbdnilo comments about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't understand what is conveyed in the link :/

Comment: Tagging the question as [tag:turboc++], since you are using a primordial 1980s dialect of the language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit tell me a thing tho, aren't almost all language same in structure and logic but different in keywords??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are they very different?

Comment: @user3500780: Yes, extremely. Compare FORTRAN with Haskell with Java with Prolog with Brainfuck with etc etc Perhaps you're only considering imperative and OO-like languages, many of which are superficially similar at least.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have problem with long lines
2. you have problem  with '\r' on windows
3. you are not looking properly at the end of line.
4. in the last line you may not have '\n'

check out this solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt");
    string str;
    int count=0;
    while(std::getline(infile,str))
    {
        string::reverse_iterator it=str.rbegin();
        while(it != str.rend() && iswspace(*it)) it++;
        if(*it =='.') count++;
    }
    cout<<"Total number of lines are:"<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with newlines on Windows since the file is opened in text mode.

Comment: I tried this program and it counts all the lines whether or not ending with '.'

Comment: @user3500780 it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is undefined if any line is longer than fifty characters (the original version is undefined if the file is longer), your end-of-file test is wrong, and the last line doesn't necessarily end with a newline.

You might write it something like this.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt");
    std::string line;
    int count = 0;
    while (infile.getline(line))
    {
        if (line.back() == '.')
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total number of lines are:" << count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned 50 as maximum line size. I tried to write a code based on that assumption

```
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt");
    char str[50]; int strSize = 50;
    int count = 0;

    while (infile.getline(str, strSize, '.')) {
        count++;
    }

    cout << "Total number of lines are:" << count << endl;

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This code basically counts the number of lines based on number of '.' present in a line, whether a sentence is in a new line or not.